# selecting options in spectron test

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, electron, spectron

I am developing an desktop application using Electron and NodeJS, what it specifically is isn't really important. I am using spectron to test my electron application. I have implemented a functionality for selecting between different saved databases through a dropdown list with options. When a database is selected in the dropdown, a json file with login credentials is updated to match the selected db. I want to write a test that checks that the json file is changed when another option is selected. My main problem is to simulate the selection of another option from a dropdown menu.

```
    // Psuedo code for what how I want to solve this
it("DB connection file is updated correctly", function() {
    read in json file with currently selected db credentials as a "before reference".
    simulate the selection of another db in the dropdown list so that json file from before is changed.
    read in changed json file
    assert.notDeepEqual(beforeFile, updatedFile);
});
```

The thing I have been stuck on is the part where I have to select another option in the dropdown to change current DB. I have read on the spectron docs and also on webdriverIO docs but I still cant get it to work.

There will always be 3 default databases listed as options in the dropdown menu. I'll list the html code for the dropdown under:

```
                        <div id="list-container">
                        <form>
                            <label id="dropdown-label" for="connection-dropdown"><b>Database</b>:</label>
                            <fieldset id="dropdown-fset">
                                <select name="database" id="connection-dropdown">
                                </select>
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

Been stuck for over a week now and I cant find any way to solve it online either. A lot of questions how to do stuff with spectron but there was no answers that helped me this time. I have probably forgot to mention something so please ask if more info is needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are able to collect elements, you can collect "select" elements under #list-container after that you can use these elements.

Answer (score 0):

> The thing I have been stuck on is the part where I have to select
>   another option in the dropdown to change current DB

I don't see any actual option elements in your HTML but if you are going to have something like this:

```
<select name="database" id="connection-dropdown">
    <option value="someValue0">uno</option>
    <option value="someValue1">dos</option>
    <option value="someValue2">tres</option>
    <option value="someValue3">cuatro</option>
    <option value="someValue4">cinco</option>
    <option value="someValue5">seis</option>
</select>
```

Then you can apply the one of several option commands. One of these is [selectByVisibleText()](http://webdriver.io/api/action/selectByVisibleText.html). That link has a nice example. Place this setup in a beforeAll().